# Remove the border the picker in react native sets

Tags: css, react-native, stylesheet, picker

I am using Picker and it has two lines one on top and one under the selection screen. I can't remove it or set it to transparent. I believe the border is for the Picker.Item and not the overall Picker, but I am not sure.

[image]

borderWidth, BaackgroundColor none will work.

```
 <Picker style={width:'50%', padding: 20, height: 100} itemStyle={height:100}}

     <Picker.item label="one" value="one" />

 </Picker>
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue